# Is it safe to delete python and pip versions 2 and 3

Tags: command-line, python

Considering mac only requires version 2.7 of python, and any version of 3, is it safe to delete to delete pip2, pip3, and python3 completely from my mac when I have v3.9 and v2.7. I found them in this folder `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, yes, since it's in `/usr/local/bin` (and so aren't the macOS system versions of python). However, you probably shouldn't just delete the executables from that directory, but the whole installation. The details of this will depend on how you did the installation, for example from Python.org, or homebrew, or anaconda.

Comment: I was trying to uninstall few versions because it was conflicting with pip, but on further inspection it seems a brew module called `python@3` was installed which is 3.9.1, while I downloaded 3.9.0 from python.org. Now I have resolved it :)

Answer (score -1):

The system version of `python2` does not come with `pip` by default. You can either install `pip` by itself, or it gets installed if you've installed a newer version of python2.7 from python.org.

However: modules installed by `pip2` for use by other `python2` installations can also be accessed by the system python. pip itself is very small, but deleting it won't remove the modules.

In short, whichever version of python2 you keep, it's useful to keep `pip` as well, if you plan to install any third-party modules.